# 文字列が３文字かどうか判定させたい

Tags: java, jsp

文字列が000−９９９であるかを判定する方法を表示させたい

**前提**

```
String no = "256";
boolean bol = ☐☐☐
out.println(bol);
```

この◻︎に処理を追記するという問題です。

３文字であるかを判定すれば良いのかと考え
`boolean bol =　no.length(３);`と入力したのですが、エラーになってしまいます。

他にできる方法が調べてもわからないので、ご教授ねがいます。

Comment: 条件は「3文字か否か」だけですか？ 
「000−999」という記述もありますので、例えば「数字（0-9）3文字」だったりしませんか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean bol = no.length() == 3;
```

ではどうでしょう

Comment: こちらで解決しました、ありがとうございます

Answer (score 1):

> 文字列が000-999であるかを判定したい

[Pattern (Java Platform SE 8 )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String no = "123";
    boolean bol = Pattern.matches("\\d{3}", no);
    System.out.println(bol);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

まずはエラーになってしまう事象を解決するために、全角文字を半角文字に直しましょう。

ご質問の`boolean bol =　no.length(３);`を実行すると下記のようなエラーが発生します。

```
.\Sample.java:9: エラー: '\u3000'は不正な文字です
        boolean bol =　no.length(３);
                     ^
.\Sample.java:9: エラー: 不正な非ASCII数字です
        boolean bol =　no.length(３);
                                ^
エラー2個
エラー: コンパイルが失敗しました
```

このエラーは、
半角のスペース( )や数字(`3`)と
全角のスペース(　)や数字(`３`)が異なる文字で、
Javaの構文として全角文字を使ってはいけない場所に使っていることが原因で発生します。

慣れないうちははまりやすいポイントですが、Javaに限らずプログラミングを習ううえで重要な概念ですので書き直して試行錯誤しながら理解してみてください。
(エラーメッセージを読むことも同じくらい重要です)

> 他にできる方法

これまでの講義や学習資料でヒントは出ていないでしょうか。

[`String#length`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/6/api/java/lang/String.html#length())は`int`型を返すので`boolean`型とは異なります。
`int`型から`boolean`型の変換は講義で習うことが多いので、学習資料に答えが載っているかもしれません。

少し高度ですが、[`String#matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/6/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String))や[`NumberFormat#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,java.text.ParsePosition))、[Character#isDigit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/6/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char))を習っているならば流用可能です。

他の回答も参考にしながらがんばってください。

**参考資料**

- [Javaで文字列が数値かどうかを確認する](https://www.techiedelight.com/ja/check-if-string-is-numeric-java/)